# Actually changing text size with OCaml Graphics

Tags: graphics, ocaml, text-size

I was wondering how to set text size in OCaml.
I tried `Graphics.set_text_size` which should do the deal I guess.

But whether I put `set_text_size 200` or `set_text_size 20` doesn't change a thing…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Graphics.set_text_size` is not implemented yet.

https://github.com/ocaml/graphics/blob/5.1.2/src/graphics.ml#L200
https://github.com/ocaml/graphics/blob/5.1.2/src/unix/text.c#L38
https://github.com/ocaml/graphics/blob/5.1.2/src/win32/draw.c#L343

Comment: The spirit of this answer seems to still hold today, since 'set_text_size' still seems like a NOP. But all the above links are broken/404.

Answer (score 4):

maybe for now, Graphics.set_text_size is not implemented yet.

But, you can use: **set_font**

```
set_font "-misc-dejavu sans mono-bold-r-normal--256-0-0-0-m-0-iso8859-1";
```

this can set font size

Comment: And how do you guess the name of a font that exists on your machine (or anyone's that matter)? For a graphics library that claims to 'provide a set of portable drawing primitives'. Having to do this kind of hackery seems a bit wrong, that isn't very 'portable' at all.