# What is the argument for Graphics.set_font from the OCaml Graphics package?

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to use the Ocaml Graphics package. I want to create a GUI for my chat server application. My code is:

```
let window = Graphics.open_graph "";
Graphics.set_window_title "caml-chat";
Graphics.set_font "ubuntu";
Graphics.set_text_size 12;
Graphics.draw_string "hello!"
```

However, `Graphics.set_font "ubuntu"` does not work. The documentation says that the string argument is system dependent, but I cannot find any more information than that. The only mention I found was in the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191127/actually-changing-text-size-with-ocaml-graphics) question, and it didn't work.

Does anyone know anything else about setting the font? (Or can point me in the direction of a simple graphics library with better documentation?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you didn't specify your system, I will assume that it is Linux (I doubt that Windows has an `ubuntu` font).

On Linux, the `set_font` function passes the argument to the X Lib's [XLoadFont](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XChar2b.3.html) function. You can use the `fc-list` or `xfontsel` utilities to query for the available fonts on your system, or call directly to the `XListFonts` function.

For example,

```
fc-list | cut -d: -f2 | sort -u
```

will give you a list of font families, which you can pass to `set_font` function. Some lines will have more than one family per line, separated with comman (`,`). There are many more options, you can specify various styles, sizes, etc. But this is all out of the scope. You can the fontconfig guide to learn more about the font subsystem. For example, [here], at the section "Font Names", you can find the explanation of how the font name is constructed.

Comment: Still does not help finding out what the function needs exactly. "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansNabataean-Regular.ttf" or "Noto Sans Nabataean" or "Noto Sans Nabataean:style=Regular" or ... ?!

Comment: It is not really in the scope of the question, basically, set_font is a thin wrapper to the corresponding operating system font subsystem. You can read more about the fontconfig system here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html 
See the "Font Names" section for the explanations and list of examples. I am not an expert in fonts neither do I understand why it is so complex, so when I need this I just take the second field (fields are separated by `:`) as the font name and it works, e.g.,  "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono".